# How to merge files to a changelist from files downloaded from another source

Tags: version-control, perforce, perforce-integrate

I have downloaded files from a source on to my local in the folder CHANGED_FILES. I want to merge these changes in perforce repo //sw/files/... and add/edit those files appropriately into a changelist 1220

I tried p4 merge -c 1220 -s CHANGED_FILES/ //sw/files which doesn't work.
Kindly help me

Comment: If you include an error message to provide context for a statement like "doesn't work" the odds of getting a specific and helpful response go up at least 500%.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a nice clean merge, here's how to manage it:

1) Branch a version of your local files that corresponds to an ancestor of the source -- for example, if the third party contributor got a snapshot of your source as of the start of the year, branch as of the start of the year, like this:

```
p4 populate -d "Creating code drop branch." //sw/files/...@2017/01/01 //third-party/CHANGED_FILES/...
```

2) Check in the modifications to the branch, just as if the third party contributor had checked them in themselves:

```
p4 sync -k //third-party/CHANGED_FILES/...
(copy the third party work into the CHANGED_FILES folder)
p4 reconcile //third-party/CHANGED_FILES/...
p4 submit -d "Code drop!"
```

3) Merge from the code drop to your own files.

```
p4 change
p4 merge -c CHANGE //third-party/CHANGED_FILES/... //sw/files/...
p4 resolve -am
p4 resolve
p4 submit
```

You can disregard this advice and just do a merge from a plain old baseless code drop, but then you will have baseless merges and your world will be pain.  The extra five minutes it takes to set up a base by doing step 1 up front is well worth it.